# Вывод функции в нужном для меня месте

Tags: php

Есть 2 файла:
index.php, main.class.php

Main.class.php содержит в себе функцию

```
    private function getproxy($type) {
      $text = file_get_contents(__DIR__."/app/temp/$type.txt");
      echo nl2br( htmlspecialchars($text) );
    }
```

и выводит ее соотвественно в index.php но в самом начале.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А надо чтобы он выводил это где-нибудь в контейнере (то есть не на самом верху.)
В php не разбираюсь.

Comment: В файле index.php в самом начале найдите то место, где эта функция выводится и перенесите ее вниз в нужный вам блок.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если на 1 уровне лежат файлы то монжо так, в индексе, укажите в любом блоке, скажем див вот так

```
<div>
<?php include(dirname(__FILE__) . "/main.class.php");  ?>
</div>
```